# How to set image view and text view side by side?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am going to make the `imageView` and `textView` side by side in a `cardView`. It looks good when in design but behaves weird when I run the app.

My `item_offer_list.xml` file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cv_iv_photo_poster"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="null"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cv_iv_photo_poster"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name">

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I have used above design in recycler view as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".OfferWallListFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llRecyclerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbLoadingItems"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNoConnection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:text="No Internet Connection" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_OfferData"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_offer_list">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My design looks good as below :

[image]

But when I run the app in emulator my image is very large but and covers all the space as below:

[image]

Why this behaves like this I dont know? Please look into it if any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're downloading images from the Internet. Maybe you forgot to specify the size of `ImaveView` in your `item_offer_list.xml`?

I mean instead of this:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

try something like this:

```
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
```

Or your own size instead of **60dp**

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two options:

1. First you can resize the bitmap image and then set it.

int maxHeight = 2000;
int maxWidth = 2000;
float scale = Math.min(((float)maxHeight / bitmap.getWidth()), ((float)maxWidth / bitmap.getHeight()));

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

2. use

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"